# Como fazer quebra de linha de uma string em PHP dentro de um div

Tags: php, html, css

Possuo uma `<div>` que cria uma caixa aonde eu deveria imprimir uma string em PHP vinda de um banco de dados, porém quando a string é muito grande, ao invés de realizar a quebra de linha a string ficava "vazada" fora da caixa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que nesses casos ocorressem uma quebra da linha.
As caixas **não** podem expandir para o lado de acordo com o tamanho da string, somente para baixo

*CSS:*

```
.box{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #4682B4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    }

.impo2 { font-family: arial; color: white; }

.ult2{
    color: white; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: large; 
    }
```

*PHP:*

```
<?php
$aaa = "hahahahaaoidhfajdhgajhgafdhgafjhgfjhadfkgafhjakjgkjdfhgajdfhgadkfjhgakfdjhgakdkajfhgakdjhgadfkjhgjafkjhdfgkjakjfdhgkadjfhgadjkhgkajhfgkjdhfgkjahfdgkajhfdg";
?>
```

*HTML:*

```
<div class="box"><center><a class="ult2"><br>Servidores com maiores erros: </a><a class="impo2"><?php echo $aaa; ?></a></center></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use o `word-wrap: break-word` no css da div que deseja, assim:

```
div {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Explicação do [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Comment: Era isso msm, muito obrigado :D

Answer (score 4):

Existem duas formas de fazer isso. Com **`word-wrap:break-word`** ou com **`word-break: break-all`** O primeiro joga a palavra para uma nova linha. Já o segundo a palavra continua na mesma linha e só quebra para baixo quando atinge a borda da div.

Veja no exemplo como é o comportamento de cada um.

```css
.box{
    width:350px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #4682B4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    }

.impo2 { font-family: arial; color: white; }

.ult2{
    color: white; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: large; 
}

.bw{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.ba{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="box bw"><center><a class="ult2"><br>Servidores com maiores erros: </a><a class="impo2">Paralelepípedo hahahahaaoidhfajdhgajhgafdhgafjhgfjhadfkgafhjakjgkjdfhgajdfhgadkfjhgakfdjhgakdkajfhgakdjhgadfkjhgjafkjhdfgkjakjfdhgkadjfhgadjkhgkajhfgkjdhfgkjahfdgkajhfdg</a></center></div>

    <div class="box ba"><center><a class="ult2"><br>Servidores com maiores erros: </a><a class="impo2">Paralelepípedo hahahahaaoidhfajdhgajhgafdhgafjhgfjhadfkgafhjakjgkjdfhgajdfhgadkfjhgakfdjhgakdkajfhgakdjhgadfkjhgjafkjhdfgkjakjfdhgkadjfhgadjkhgkajhfgkjdhfgkjahfdgkajhfdg</a></center></div>
```

Comment: Boa resposta! Melhor explicada que a minha :s

Comment: Só complementei ;)